# CMD: Zipping files from source path (variable)

Tags: batch-file, cmd, zip

In case when pdf file exist I'd like to zip it with .docx file (same filenames). After adding source variable my batch breaks - dunno why exactly.

```
echo. Input source path
set /p "source="
set "destination=C:\Users\<user_name>\Documents"    
for "%source%\%%f" in (*.docx) do if exist "%source%\%%~nf.pdf" 7za.exe a -tzip -mx5 -mmt=on "%destination%\%%~nf.zip" "%source%\%%~nf.docx" "%source%\%%~nf.pdf"
```

Comment: Double check you are inputting the source path correctly. Make sure the path does not end in a `\ `  or your batch file will be referring as `"%source%\\%%f"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling the `for` loop incorrectly. You need to put `%source%` inside the parentheses. `%%f` is the variable, not the source file.

```
for %%f in (%source%\*.docx) do if exist "%source%\%%~nf.pdf" 7za.exe a -tzip -mx5 -mmt=on "%destination%\%%~nf.zip" "%source%\%%~nf.docx" "%source%\%%~nf.pdf"
```